# Convexity of log sum function

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

Is $f\left( x \right)=\log \left( \sum_i \beta_i e^{-\alpha_ix} \right)$ a convex function where $\beta_i,\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the summation index? If not $\log(5e^{-x}+e^x)$ is not convex. Just plot it and you'll see.

Comment: @mtiano: The second derivative is $\frac{20}{(5e^{-x}+e^x)^2}$ which looks positive.

Comment: @robjohn: $(\ln(f))' = f'/f$, so $\log(5e^{-x}+e^x)' = (-5e^{-x}+e^x)/(5e^{-x}+e^x)$ and similarly for $(\ln f)''$. I think you forgot the $f'$ part.

Comment: @martycohen: $$
\begin{align}
\log\left(5e^{-x}+e^x\right)
&\mapsto\frac{-5e^{-x}+e^x}{5e^{-x}+e^x}\\
\frac{-5e^{-x}+e^x}{5e^{-x}+e^x}
&\mapsto\frac{\left(5e^{-x}+e^x\right)^2-\left(-5e^{-x}+e^x\right)^2}{\left(5e^{-x}+e^x\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{20}{\left(5e^{-x}+e^x\right)^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no restrictions on $\beta_i$ and $\alpha_i$ then there are counter-examples, e.g.
$$
g(x) = 2 e^{0 x} - 2 e^{-1x} + 1e^{-2x}.$$
We have $g(x)>0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with a minimum at $x=0$, but the second derivative of $f(x) \equiv \log(g(x))$ changes sign near $x=0$.
[image]

Comment: Have about with restrictions $\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\mathop \sum }}\,{{\beta}_{i}}=1,{{\beta }_{i}}\in \left[ 0,~1 \right],{{\alpha }_{i}}\in \{-1,1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

The function $f(x)=\log g(x)$ ($g\in C^2((a,b),(0,\infty)$) is convex iff $(\log g(x))’’\ge 0$ that is $g’’(x)g(x)\ge g’(x)^2$. In our case $g(x)=\sum_i \beta_i e^{-\alpha_ix}$, $g’(x)=\sum_i -\alpha_i \beta_i e^{-\alpha_ix}$, 
$g’’(x)=\sum_i \alpha_i^2 \beta_i e^{-\alpha_ix}$. If all $\beta_i$ are non-negative then the inequality $g’’(x)g(x)\ge g’(x)^2$ follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.